# Help fixing Grease Pencil strokes

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm brand new to Blender. I downloaded Blender on my Kamvas 13. I only use it for 2D animation. I'm having an issue with the pencil lines. When I draw circles it starts off smooth then it becomes angular. I've tried to fix it by going into the Strokes option but I'm lost. Please help.[image]

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots. The current ones are quite hard to see. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Would you or anyone be able to assist with navigating through Grease Pencil so i can draw properly? Again my lines become angular as indicated in the picture with the red arrows.